# Discord имитация используя Discum

Tags: discord

Всем привет, хочу Имитировать присутствия пользователя в голосовом канале через дикум, но не получается.

```html
import discum

def join_voice_channel(token, guild_id, channel_id):
    try:
        bot = discum.Client(token=token, log={"console": True, "file": False})
        bot.gateway.fetchMembers(guild_id)  # Получаем информацию о пользователях на сервере

        payload = {
            "op": 4,
            "d": {
                "guild_id": str(guild_id),
                "channel_id": str(channel_id),
                "self_mute": False,
                "self_deaf": False
            }
        }

        bot.gateway.session.send(opcode=4, data=payload)  # Отправляем данные для присоединения к голосовому каналу
        bot.gateway.run()  # Запускаем соединение с шлюзом Discord

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to join voice channel: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    user_token = "YOUR_USER_TOKEN"
    guild_id = "YOUR_GUILD_ID"
    channel_id = "YOUR_CHANNEL_ID"

    join_voice_channel(user_token, guild_id, channel_id)
```

Библиотеки дискорд.ру не подходять, так как нужно работать с токена пользователя. Есть альтернативные решения ?